# Can we implement client side load balancing with Ribbon with Spring boot 2.5.2?

Tags: spring-cloud-netflix

we are trying to upgrade our code from spring boot 1.x to spring boot 2.5.2 and we were taking advantage of ribbon for client side load balancing with older version of spring boot (1.x).

Now, when I'm referring to the spring cloud netflix documentation, they are still referring to 'ribbon' for client side load balancing here

https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-netflix#overview.

But, some other place, spring documentation says, they dropped support for netflix ribbon in recent spring boot and i see the spring boot cloud starter is not pulling the ribbon dependencies when i switch to spring boot 2.5.2

Now, my question is, if i upgrade my Spring boot version from 1.x to 2.5.2 and add the netflix ribbon dependencies ( explicitly) can i still take advantage of ribbon for client side load balancing ?

All i'm trying to understand is, would spring boot 2.5.2 work with netflix ribbon (if i add the netflix ribbon dependencies by myself) ?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Cloud Netflix Ribbon is no longer supported. We suggest using Spring Cloud LoadBalancer as a replacement. You can find the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#spring-cloud-loadbalancer) and a guide [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-cloud-loadbalancer/). We suggest using [start.spring.io](https://start.spring.io/) to find out the versions of Spring Cloud compatible with the supported versions of Spring Boot.

Comment: Thanks for the response. where can i find a guide ( example ) for implementing client load balancing using Spring Cloud Loadbalancer + openFeign ?

Comment: Here's a sample that uses both: https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/feign-eureka. Unless you're adding custom config (which is described in the docs linked above), you only need to have `spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer` dependency on your classpath.